# SwiftUI: Drawing a rectangle using Path

Tags: swiftui

Can someone explain how the below SwiftUI code is drawing a triangle?

```
var body: some View {
    Path { p in
        p.addLines([
            CGPoint(x: 50, y: 0),
            CGPoint(x: 100, y: 50),
            CGPoint(x: 0, y: 50)
        ])}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the Path closes the last line with the first line automatically. As the why your current code is producing a triangle see this image:

[image]

A rectangle, in your case, would be:

```
Path { p in
p.addLines([
    CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0),
    CGPoint(x: 150, y: 0),
    CGPoint(x: 150, y: 100),
    CGPoint(x: 0, y: 100)
])}
```

Or just:

```
Path(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 100))
```

Comment: or you can add `path.move(to: CGPoint(x:0,y:0)) ` at the beginning to initiate path start point

Comment: @Aspid i removed the path.move from my question, what does it achieve? Would not the Path start at 0,0 by default?

Comment: @Faraaz you can draw several figures in one path. To do so use move(to:) and closeSubpath(). I think they are for that purpose